# Creating Icon Component in React based on Fontawesom icons

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, styled-components

I'm trying to build my ui library based on styled system and styled components and storybook, and when I came to implemeting an Icon component I'm having some doubts about my approach.
here is my approach:

1. File Structrue:

   ```
       Componenets/
       |    Icon/
       |    |    Icon.js
       |    |    index.js
       |    ...
       ...
   ```
2. in index.js I import all the needed icons in my app and create a library so all the icons will be  available for my icon component.

```
import {
    faGlobe,
    faPhone,
    faEnvelope,
    faSms,
    faWifi
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(
    faGlobe,
    faPhone,
    faEnvelope,
    faSms,
    faWifi);

export { default } from './Icon'
```

1. Icon.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import theme from '../../../Theme';

const Icon = props => {
    return (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} color={theme.colors[props.color]} />
    )
}

export default Icon
```

and like that I'll be using my component directly

```
<Icon icon="phone" color="primary" />
```

Comment: What are your doubts?

Comment: the location of the library